# Finding the condition for root of a third degree polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, conditional

I've a third degree polynomial (in $s$):

$$as^3+bs^2+cs+d\tag1$$

I need to find the roots of the polynomial, so I can use the code:

```
Solve[a*s^3 + b*s^2 + c*s + d == 0, s]
```

Now, there are three solutions because it is a third degree polynomial.

> Now, the question: I need to find the condition for which all three of the roots of the polynomial have a real part that is strictly smaller then zero. Can I find that condition?

Comment: This might take a very long time: `Resolve[ForAll[s, s^3 + b*s^2 + c*s + d == 0, Re[s] < 0], s]`.

Comment: It would be worth knowing more about how the problem arises (my guess would be this is a stability test for a control system). The Routh test determines whether all the roots of the characteristic polynomial of a linear system have negative real parts, and there are easy ways to apply the Routh–Hurwitz stability criterion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh–Hurwitz_stability_criterion).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming real coefficients and a=1, following Daniel Lichtblau comment, conditions are quickly found by:

`Resolve[ForAll[s, s^3 + b*s^2 + c*s + d == 0, Re[s] < 0] && 
  Element[d, Reals] && Element[c, Reals] && Element[b, Reals]]`

with simple answer:

`b > 0 && c > 0 && 0 < d < b c`.

Quantifier elimination is known to work for problems like this.

Comment: Nice (and an upvote). It did not occur to me to add those real variable specifications.

Answer (score 7):

Since `a != 0` then without loss of generality you can set `a == 1`

```
poly = #^3 + b*#^2 + c*# + d &;
```

The conditions can be found very rapidly if the three roots are real. Further, assuming that you want three distinct roots,

```
(* cond = Reduce[{Root[poly, 1] < 0, Root[poly, 2] < 0, Root[poly, 3] < 0, 
    Root[poly, 1] < Root[poly, 2] < Root[poly, 3]}, {b, c, d}, Reals] // 
  FullSimplify *)
```

**EDIT:** written more simply

```
cond = Reduce[{Root[poly, 1] < Root[poly, 2] < Root[poly, 3] < 0}, {b,
     c, d}, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Generating some examples

```
SeedRandom[0];
cond5 = FindInstance[cond, {b, c, d}, Integers, 5];
```

Checking,

```
Grid[{#, NSolve[poly[s] == 0 /. #, s, Reals]} & /@ cond5, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: It seems more difficult, though, if what you need is `Re[Root[..]]<0` for complex roots (the usual control theory problem).

Comment: @yarchik - For `a != 0` then `s^3 + b s^2 + c s + d` has the same roots as `a s^3 + (a b) s^2 + (a c) s + (a d)` which is the original form. Or starting with the original form and `a != 0` then `a s^3 + b s^2 + c  s + d` has the same roots as `s^3 + (b/a) s^2 + (c/a) s + (d/a)`. The `cond /. b -> 0` evaluating to `False` indicates that there is no `c` and `d` for which `s^3 + c s + d` has **three distinct negative (i.e., real) roots** (the simplified case that I indicated that I was addressing).

Comment: @BobHanlon My comment was not well thought. You are right. The `s^3 + c s + d==0` equation cannot have 3 negative roots on the basis of Vieta's formulas.